# Loading MassTransit consumers from an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

When loading **MT** consumers from an assembly (using `StructureMap` container / `MassTransit.StructureMap` integration nuget package) messages get handled partially: bus handles messages stored in the queue and doesn't respond after that, though you can see messages added into the queue. Then if you restart the application it will handle those awaiting messages in the queue and will do nothing more.

Here's the setup:

```
public class Application {
    public static void Main() {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Configure(c => c.Scan(scan => {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.AddAllTypesOf<IConsumer>();
        }));

        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc => {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/app_commands");
            sbc.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(container));
            sbc.Validate();
        });

        container.Inject(bus);

        Console.WriteLine("* mt bus has been registered");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The corresponding consumer is in the same assembly. If I change subscription code to this:

```
sbc.Subscribe(x => x.Consumer<SendDocumentCommandHandler>().Permanent());
```

specifying the consumer type explicitly and making it permanent it will respond to incoming commands.

Are the consumers registered with use of `LoadFrom` permanent?

---

consumer code:

```
public class SendDocumentCommandHandler : Consumes<SendDocumentCommand>.All {
    private IServiceBus bus;

    public void Consume(SendDocumentCommand message) {
        Console.WriteLine("Message of type: {0} has been consumed", message.GetType().Name);
    }

    public SendDocumentCommandHandler() { }

    public SendDocumentCommandHandler(IServiceBus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }
}
```

Comment: And yes, ```LoadFrom``` is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the lifecycle of `IServiceBus` (being `IDisposable`) is not being ended prematurely by StructureMap. Where you have injected the `IServiceBus` into the consumer, it's likely that when the consumer is disposed, the bus is being shutdown.

So the `container.Inject()` may need some additional properties on it to avoid it being disposed by StructureMap.

Also, you can use `IConsumeContext` to get the `IServiceBus` (using the `Bus` property), so there is no need to inject it into the consumer.